# Removing unwanted lines from the file

Tags: text-processing

I have eight file's which start with: `SEALS-*`

Each file has a header and data:

```
#Col_1\Col_2\Col_3\col_4    --- header
\\\\\\\\\\                  --- data
```

If it is a null entry, I need to delete this record; it has only `\`'s on the line.

Comment: If i have null in any file i will get only Header and  " \\\\\\\ " as a data column  which i need to delete that 1 line alone.

Comment: find -type f -exec sh -c '[[ $(sed -n $= $0) -eq 2 ]]' {} \; -exec sed -i '1!d' {} +
tried with this which delets 2nd line even it has data, but i need to delete if it has only \\\\\\\\\\\

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please add your updates into the Question. If you leave them as comments they can get lost in noise. Please would you also format your question text and include examples of "before" and "after" data files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Perl's `i` flag for [in-place edits](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

```
$ perl -pi -e '$_ = "" if m{^\\\\}' file.txt
```

And if you want to pipe the output of `find` to it, use `xargs`:

```
$ find . -type f | xargs perl -pi -e '$_ = "" if m{^\\\\}'
```

When using `find`'s `-exec` instruction:

```
$ find . -type f -exec perl -pi -e '$_ = "" if m{^\\\\}' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks much guys 
this worked out 
find -name "SALE-*" -type f -exec sh -c '[[ $(sed -n $= $0) -eq 2 ]]' {} \; -exec sed -i '/^[\\\]*$/d' {} +

Answer (score 0):

## First answer :

For all that is text manipulation, Perl is always a good possibility :

```
perl -e 'while(<>){print if(!/(\\\\)+/)}' file > file.new
```

But if you only want to use the shell, this could work too :

```
grep -v '\\\\' file > file.new
```

It works well :)

## Edit :

If you can't create a new file, Perl can still do that :

```
perl -e 'open FILE_R, "+<$ARGV[0]"; @line=<FILE_R>; open FILE_W,"+>$ARGV[0]"; foreach(@line){print FILE_W if(!/(\\\\)+/);}' file
```

Let me explain this long line :

```
open FILE_R, "+<$ARGV[0]"; @line=<FILE_R>;
```

=> Open your file on "read" mode, and copy all data into an array

```
open FILE_W,"+>$ARGV[0]"; foreach(@line){print FILE_W if(!/(\\\\)+/);}
```

=> Open and truncate your file on "write" mode, and write all data (but your \\ lines) into it.

I recommend [this tool](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=519264) if you want to learn more about Perl  :)

Comment: I should not recreate the file,with out recreating can i do that